# pyOpenGL won't work

Tags: python, opengl, pygame

i want to make a 3d rotating cube using pygame and pyopengl after watching a tutorial on Youtube but i keep getting an error. i installed opengl using my terminal.

here is the code

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import pygame


sharps=(
    (1,1,-1),
    (-1,1,-1),
    (-1,-1,-1),
    (1,-1,-1),
    (1,1,1),
    (-1,1,1),
    (-1,-1,1),
    (1,-1,1)
    )
lines=(
    (0,1),
    (1,2),
    (2,3),
    (3,0),
    (0,4),
    (4,5),
    (5,6),
    (6,7),
    (7,4),
    (5,1),
    (6,2),
    (7,3)
    )

def cube():
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for x in lines:
        for y in x:
            glVertex3fv(sharps[y])
    glEnd()



def main():
    pygame.init()
    x=800
    y=600
    window=pygame.display.set_mode((x,y), DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
    gluPerspective(45,(x/y),0.1,50.0)
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-5)
    glRotatef(0,0,0,0)

    true = True
    while true:
     for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type==pygame.QUIT:
            true=False

     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
     cube()
     pygame.display.flip()
     pygame.time.wait(10)

try:
    main()
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

and the error

> global name 'DOUBLEBUF' is not defined

i dont seem to understand where the problem lie, i mean it worked for the guy in youtube.Please help

Answer (score 1):

DOUBLEBUF is defined in pygame, so you have to write:

```
pygame.DOUBLEBUF
```

You could also change your import to:

```
from pygame import *
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. I had frustrating week trying to figure it out.